# Inducing positive charge on a Sphere(Metallic)

Tags: electrostatics

Sorry if this question is asked already. I want to know that while inducing positive charge on a neutral body, at the time of earthing why the electrons move out so easily from the neutral body to the ground.I wonder Is it that easy to remove the electrons from a body. And aren't there a lots of electrons already in the ground so that if electrons are moving through earthing to ground will be repelled back to the body. Hope I will get a reply soon Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The potential of earth is consider to be zero so charge can easily flow into earth as charge flow from body at higher potential to lower potential.Also the earth is so large that the addition of electrons dont increase the charge of earth they will simply lost in the earth.

Answer (score 0):

When charge is induced on a body that induced charge is being held in position by another charged object which I shall assume to be negatively charged.

On the body with the induced charge there will be a separation of charges with the part of the body nearest the negatively charged object having a net positive charge and being attracted by the negatively charged object and the part furthest from the negatively charged object having a net negative charge and being repelled by the negatively charged object.

Given an opportunity that negative induced charge will get further away from the negatively charged object.

The Earth (and any other uncharged body) certainly does have a lot of electrons as part of its composition but it also has approximately as many protons, so it is in effect neutral.

Connecting the Earth to the body with the induced charges on it will result in the negative induced charges moving further away (to the Earth) from the negatively charged object which is causing the induction leaving the body with a net positive charge.

It does not have to be the Earth which produces the movement of the negative induced charge as shown below.

[image]